# React + Redux + Firebase: understanding how a dispatcher works

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, redux-thunk, dispatcher

I am learning React by creating a React app (following ~2 tutorials). Things got a bit messy, so I wanted to know what this function containing a dispatcher does exactly:

```
export const fetchProjects = () => async dispatch => {
    projectsRef.once("value", snapshot => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'FETCH_PROJECTS',
        payload: snapshot.val()
      });
    });
  };
```

Note that `projectRef.once` comes from this line of code in the fbConfig file:

```
const databaseRef = firebase.database().ref();
export const projectsRef = databaseRef.child('projects');
//the setup is working properly because I am succefully writing into the DB in another part of the app
```

**For context:** this function belongs in a 'actions' file. It is being called by another component called ProjectList using a lifecycle method. Here is the whole code of ProjectList.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import ProjectSummary from './ProjectSummary'
import _ from "lodash";
import * as actions from '../../store/actions/projectActions'
import { connect } from "react-redux";

class ProjectList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  renderProjects(){
    const { data } = this.props;
    const allprojects = _.map(data, (value, key) => {
      return <ProjectSummary key={key} project={value} />;
    });
    if (!_.isEmpty(allprojects)) {
      return allprojects;
    }
    return (
      <div className="col s10 offset-s1 center-align">
        <h4>You have no projects</h4>
        <p>Start by going to New Project and creating a new project</p>
      </div>
    );

  }

  componentWillMount() { 
    this.props.fetchProjects();
  }
  render() { 

  return (
      <div className="project-list section">
         {this.renderProjects()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ data }) => {
  return {
    data
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, action)(ProjectList);
```

Here is the reducer that has the above action as a case:

```
const initState = {
  projects: []
}

const projectReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
     case 'FETCH_PROJETCS':
       return action.payload;
    case 'CREATE_PROJECT_SUCCESS':
      console.log('create project success');
      console.log(action.project);
      return state;
    case 'CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR':
      console.log('create project error');
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default projectReducer;
```

My problem is that I don't understand where the 'payload' in the initial `fetchProjects` method is going (is it updating the state? Which part of the state?). This part of the application is not working as expected (I can't manage to load data from the DB). Thanks for any help in clearing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, actually redux is actually is a big topic. but I will give you short explanation about what is happening in your code.

There are 3 important things in redux -

1. Store
2. Actions
3. Reducers

Each one has its job.
The store is for actually storing your application data. Actions are for indicating what actions/operation needs to perform on application data/store
And finally, reducers are actually to change store state according to payload received from actions.
Now understand the flow of your code or how it works -

- You are calling a function inside componentWillMount - `fetchProjects`, this will call action inside your action file.
- Then inside action `fetchProjects` once you received snapshot it will dispatch that action(in short it calls reducers with payload)
  Now point to note here is `dispatch` is a function of the Redux store. You call the store. dispatch to dispatch an action. This is the only way to trigger a state change.
  And `action` object contains action `type` and `payload` based on which reducers updated the store.
- Then at last in your reducer `projectReducer` according to action type in switch case, it will execute that block of code.  and here you can perform state manipulation as per payload received.
  And you now your state has been updated with the return value of state from the reducer.
  And it must return state from the reducer.

```
switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_PROJETCS':
       return { 
           projects: action.payload    //this will update projects array inside store
           }
    case 'CREATE_PROJECT_SUCCESS':
      console.log('create project success');
      console.log(action.project);
      return state;
    case 'CREATE_PROJECT_ERROR':
      console.log('create project error');
      return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
```

References-
https://redux.js.org/api/store#store
https://redux.js.org/faq/actions